# Redis Disk Size Coincidence?

Tags: redis, ubuntu-12.04

I'm still quite new to Redis, and I'm doing some testing regarding memory and disk space, and I've encountered an odd situation. I added 1,000,000 string type records to Redis, 50,000 at a time, and shortly after I finished, my Ubuntu box started showing "low disk space" messages. I assumed it must be the RDB file, but, after deleting all but 100,000 of the records, my RDB file is only 28.5MB, but disk usage remains at 3.2GB. Before I started, it was only at about 1GB. Is it just a weird coincidence that disk use spiked, or am I missing something? The funny thing is, the only thing I'm using the Ubuntu instance for is Redis, so I can't imagine where another giant file would come from. Thoughts?

```
Specs:
Ubuntu 12.04.3 (running on VirtualBox)
Redis  2.2.12
Redis maxmemory 2GB
Redis appendonly no
```

Comment: If your dump operation has been interrupted because of lack of disk space, you may want to check if a temp file is present in Redis dump directory. The RDB dump process generates a temp file, and then renames it. If it fails before the rename operation, the temp file may remain. Just delete it.

Comment: @DidierSpezia Thanks for the quick reply. I checked the /var/lib/redis directory, and I don't see any temporary files. I've restarted my Ubuntu/VirtualBox instance, and disk usage remains the same. My total disk space allotment is 4GB, and I have the UI installed (ubuntu-desktop) -- maybe I was running low already and just didn't notice?

Answer (score 0):

The disk-space spike was coincidental: I had sized my VirtualBox too small to begin with, and even the tiny RDB file (and occasional temp RDB file) was pushing the file-system to its limits. I created a new machine with more disk space, and everything is fine. Even at 1,000,000 string-type records, my RDB file was only 285MB. Thanks, Redis!